# how to place inline divs using angular material?

Tags: angular

I am trying to place inline divs inside the first row. I failed to inline them.

I would appreciate if anyone can show me the way how it can be done.
Here is the stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ry9yry

```
<mat-grid-list cols = "4" rowHeight = "80px">
   <mat-grid-tile 
   [colspan] = "4"
   [rowspan] = "1">

<div fxLayout="row inline" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center" >
  <div fxFlex="25"> 1. One</div>
  <div fxFlex="25">2. Two</div>
  <div fxFlex="25">3. Three</div>
  <div fxFlex="25">4. Four</div>
</div>

  </mat-grid-tile>
     <mat-grid-tile
   [colspan] = "4"
   [rowspan] = "1">date
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile 
   [colspan] = "2"
   [rowspan] = "1">item
</mat-grid-tile>
<mat-grid-tile 
   [colspan] = "2"
   [rowspan] = "1">variation
   </mat-grid-tile>
<mat-grid-tile 
   [colspan] = "4"
   [rowspan] = "1">summary
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

Comment: The problem is that in the example at least, you do not have @angular/flex-layout, even installed or imported into your application. Without the installation and import of that module, fxLayout and fxLayoutAlign will simply not have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use flexbox to style them instead of fxLayout:

```
div{
 display: flex;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

Edited after comments:

If you would like to use fxLayout, the problem is that it is not installed in your app. To do that you need to follow those steps:

installation:

```
npm install @angular/flex-layout @angular/cdk --save
```

import to the module:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {FlexLayoutModule} from '@angular/flex-layout';
// other imports 
@NgModule({
 imports: [FlexLayoutModule],
 ...
})
export class YourAppModule {}
```

https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Using-Angular-CLI

To compare above solutions, please check comment bellow that was added by  Alexander Staroselsky

Comment: They are using flex already. The directives `fxLayout` and `fxLayoutAlign` are [@angular/flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) directives that inject flex styles into angular applications and components.

Comment: What is the advantage then if you need to import it and css flexbox is already there ready to use?

Comment: If you are building an Angular application, it exposes a large number of directives that make it easier to achieve complex layouts. It also exposes Angular specific utilities to listen for breakpoint/media changes. That question is pretty broad though. You could ask why do frameworks exist and why are they used in large numbers? I see that you've answered questions about jQuery, I could ask you why use jQuery over pure JavaScript? Either way, they were expecting those directives to work without having the necessary dependencies installed and/or registered.

Comment: Thank you Adam that solved my problem but as Alexander indicated anguar already using flex layout why is it not working then?

Comment: @david83 is that sample application is a reflection of your actual application, you have not installed `@angular/flex-layout`. It is NOT included with @angular/material, it is a separate package. That is why the flex directives are not working.

Comment: Here there are instructions how to do that: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Using-Angular-CLI